# android "Use ringtone volume for notifications"

Tags: android, notifications, volumes

I'm trying to change the volume of notification stream (not ring) on a HTC One with android 4.3. I'm using this code:

```
int setting = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), "notifications_use_ring_volume", -20);
boolean b = Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "notifications_use_ring_volume", 1 - setting);
```

so everytime b is true(meaning that the change has been made) and everytime I'm putting 0 or 1. Now, after I'm changing the value, when I read it, it displays the value that I've updated in the avove code, but when I'm going to Settings->Sound->Volumes, the

**"Use ringtone volume for notifications"**

checkbox remains unchanged (when that setting is 0 or 1). Am I missing something here? How to update this setting from code so I can see in the phone's settings this change?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html). It has a method named, [setStreamVolume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29) which helps you manipulate volume for Audio streams.

Here's a sample application which demonstrates what you want. [Link to sample applcation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/SystemServices/Volume/src/com/commonsware/android/syssvc/volume/Volumizer.java).

Comment: yes, but first, I have to "separate" those two streams if that setting exists. And if it exists, I have to set "notifications_use_ring_volume" setting to 0, because otherwise the ting stream and notification streams are related and changing ring stream also changes notification stream. So my problem is changing this setting so I can see the changes in the settings screen.

Comment: @BudaGavril Android ICS and onwards has merged the ringer and notification volumes into one volume. There is no way via code to unlink these volume controls. However, you can wire up a adjust the new unified notification volume based on conditions. Say for example, you can use Audio Control when someone calls, it applies a pre-chosen volume setting to mimic the ringer volume and adjusts back to the prior setting after the call has ended.

Comment: I know that, but if that setting (Use ringtone volume for notifications) exists, if you uncheck that, you can have separate streams. And I want to uncheck it from code but I'm not able to do that. that is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION), AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

You can control volume, to change second parameter. (am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION))

[setStreamVolume(int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: if android os is 4.0 or above, the ring and notification streams are related and changing one of this two, changes and the other one and I don't want to change both, as I've stated above

Answer (score -1):

Create a "raw" folder inside your application resource folder and place the ringtone(.mp3) file
inside that raw folder and then add this line when you receive the notification.

> notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
>                 + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sapphire);

OR

```
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sapphire);
```

And then create and your intent and pending Intent and call this

> notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, message, title,
>   pendingIntent);
>    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

Comment: it's not working, but why do you need to create a notification for this task?